# ANSIBLE - Handlers listen

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Really short question. I just wanted to know why when we use handlers the "listen" section doesn't take variable?

```yaml
- name: notify components 
  command: echo "this task will notify all the components"
  notify: "hello world"
```

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "Hello world !!"
  listen: "hello world"

- set_fact:
    myvar: "hello world"
  listen: "hello world"

- debug:
    msg: "Hello world !! with var"
  listen: "{{myvar}}"
```

Why this section doesn't work? Listen doesn't take variables?

Comment: please format this properly, as whitespace is quite critical for reading ansible.

Comment: You can build handlers on the fly if you want to. FWIW see [config_light](https://ansible-config-light.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#cl-handlers-dictionary-with-handlers).

Answer (score 1):

This is specifically documented in the notes on [handlers documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change)

> Handler names are templatable and listen topics are not.